Is it possible to replicate this type of Nested scrollview using swiftUi
how can I replicate this type of nested scrollview using swiftUI.
This is my attempt
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            
            HStack{
                
                LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {
                    
                    Section (header:
                                Text("Header One")
                             // give background here
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .background(.gray)
                    ) {
                        ForEach(0..<5) { item in
                            Text("Item \(item)")
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                
                
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {
                        Section {
                            ForEach(0..<5) { item in
                                HStack{
                                    ForEach(0..<9) { item in
                                        Text("Item \(item)")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } header: {
                            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                                Text("a")
                                    .frame(width: 80)
                                Text("b")
                                    .frame(width: 80)
                                Text("d")
                                    .frame(width: 100)
                                Text("i")
                                    .frame(width: 80)
                                
                                Text("e")
                                    .frame(width: 80)
                                Text("f")
                                    .frame(width: 100)
                                Text("g")
                                    .frame(width: 100)
                                Text("h")
                                    .frame(width: 100)
                            }
                            .font(.caption)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .padding(.vertical, 8)
                            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        .font(.title2)
        .padding()
    }
}

in my approach the vertical header ("Header One") pins correctly. However, the horizontal header ("a", "b", "c", etc.) scrolls vertically along with the content instead of remaining pinned horizontally at the top of the horizontal section.

Have you tried Table it might be able to do what you want

@Chairman you might want to try Introspect or UICollectionView
