Issues Using SwiftUI Table on iOS 16: "Argument type '[Person]' does not conform to expected type 'Decoder'"
I'm trying to use the new Table view in SwiftUI for iOS 16 to display a list of people with columns for their given name, family name, and email address. According to Apple's documentation, Table should be available on iOS 16, but I'm encountering an error that says:
Argument type '[Person]' does not conform to expected type 'Decoder'

Here's the code I am using:
struct Person: Identifiable {
    let givenName: String
    let familyName: String
    let emailAddress: String
    let id = UUID()

    var fullName: String { givenName + " " + familyName }
}

struct PeopleTable: View {
    @State private var people = [
        Person(givenName: "Juan", familyName: "Chavez", emailAddress: "juanchavez@icloud.com"),
        Person(givenName: "Mei", familyName: "Chen", emailAddress: "meichen@icloud.com"),
        Person(givenName: "Tom", familyName: "Clark", emailAddress: "tomclark@icloud.com"),
        Person(givenName: "Gita", familyName: "Kumar", emailAddress: "gitakumar@icloud.com")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        Table(people) {
            TableColumn("Given Name", value: \.givenName)
            TableColumn("Family Name", value: \.familyName)
            TableColumn("E-Mail Address", value: \.emailAddress)
        }
    }
}



I've confirmed that:

My deployment target is set to iOS 17.
I'm using Xcode 15.4.
The List works without any issues in place of Table.
Is there something I'm missing in the configuration, or is this a bug with SwiftUI's Table on iOS? Has anyone successfully used Table in iOS 16?

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Just add Decoder to Person, next to Identifiable

Did you declare your own type called Table somewhere else in your project? I pasted the code into a new project and could not reproduce the error.

@Sweeper this was the problem, turns out I had a model Struct Table in my code. Thanks for the help

@Sweeper in the case where it decides there is not enough space on iPhone to render all columns, how can one render the remaining columns

That doesn't make sense. You cannot magically create more space. That said, the documentation already tells you how to detect when there is not enough space, and recommends that you put more information in the first column.

@Sweeper is it possible to achieve this data presentation using Table, this was a previous question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78988676/is-it-possible-to-replicate-this-type-of-nested-scrollview-using-swiftui

that is not possible as its already stated by @Sweeper, new spaces cannot be magically created, you should try another approach

@chairman have you considered using Introspect or UICollectionView

@OmotayoSamson I think you replied to the wrong person.

@OmotayoSamson I have no idea how to use introspect
